# SQL different behaviour of REFERENCE word

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, create-table

I started working in a new project which I have program in C# and use SQL server.
Database is starting to get a bit more complicated but nothing to worry about yet, but yesterday I found somewhere in Stack Overflow a new way to relate tables.

**Table A**

```
CREATE TABLE tableA (
    Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    name varchar(50),
    CONSTRAINT tablea_pk PRIMARY KEY (Id))
```

**Table B**

```
CREATE TABLE tableB (
    Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    name varchar(50),
    idA int NOT NULL REFERENCES TableA(Id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT tableB_pk PRIMARY KEY (Id))
```

**Table C**

```
CREATE TABLE tableC (
    Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    name varchar(50),
    idB int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tableC_fk_tableB FOREIGN KEY(idB)
        REFERENCES tableB(Id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

I suspect both ways of creating references do exactly the same, the only difference is when you create the reference in table B you don't specify a constraint name for the Foreign Key so the Foreign Key's name is generated randomly as I can see in sysobjects table:

```
SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name LIKE '%FK%'
```

[image: foreign keys]

The questions are: do both REFERENCES work EXACTLY the same way? Is it the same if I create a constraint Foreign Key... or if I reference a PK from column's definition line?

I don't know if this can be done only in SQL server or it's something general from SQL and also I tried finding information about it on Google but I hadn't had any luck (maybe because I don't know what I'm looking for)

Answer (score 1):

It's the same, and you can also name your constraint inline in table B like this :

```
CREATE TABLE tableB (
Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
name varchar(50),
idA int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_TableB_TableA REFERENCES TableA(Id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT tableB_pk PRIMARY KEY (Id))
go
```